# Scrollable list of text fields (a form) with tab navigation

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

**Goal**: Implement a vertically scrollable list of custom editable items (a text field + a button). The list and its items should autoresize in the horizontal direction. Tab / Shift-Tab navigation should navigate between the text fields.

**Current solution**: A one column NSTableView with view-based cells. But there is a problem with the Tab navigation. NSTableView handles the Tab key in its own way. I've tried all the subclassing hacks from SO, but failed to implement a normal Tab / Shift-Tab navigation between text fields.

**Alternative solution**: I've also tried making a custom stack view inside NSScrollView, but failed to make its subviews to autoresize.

**Question**: Looking for an open-source example or an advice from those who done such a thing before. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I spent the day fighting key view loop behavior of NSTableView. I quite easily got the basics working by overriding keyDown:. Problem is that if a NSTableCellView has a text field, NSTableView insists on giving it focus first. A working hack seems to be to nest the text field(s) in a custom view. I.e. NSTableCellView hosts a NSView which hosts NSTextField

Comment: @PierreBernard Just tried your advice and it does not work. Adding a host NSView gives no difference. Sometimes the table 'eats' every second tab hit. Sometimes the focus hangs on a single row. It seems hacking NSTableView is a wrong way. Even if I manage to make it work, it might be broken in the next OS version.

Comment: I had the above working in a view based NSOutlineView. I.e by nesting text fields in a view I got sensible behavior when moving focus into a table row. My NSOutlineView subclass handles Tab key to move to next key view. When the window itself becomes first responder, I move to the next row. Interestingly, first responder only seems to move to the window when using bindings. W/o bindings the next key view for any row in the table is the next button below the table.